# wget fails on a local domain

Tags: php, apache, wget

I have a Red Hat linux box with apache running several domains, including a.com and b.com.

I have a php script a.com/wget.php, which makes an exec() call to download a file on the local domain b.com. Running the php script from the command line is successful.

But running this script from a web page results in a 404 error. The command is:

```
    /usr/bin/wget -k -S --save-headers --keep-session-cookies 
    -O <local-file-name> -o <local-log-file-name> -U \"Mozilla/5.0
    (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 
    Firefox/24.0\" --max-redirect=100 "http://b.com/page.php"
```

No log messages are written to the Apache access log file for domain b.com for this call.

BUT the server access log file (/var/log/httpd/access_log) is NOT empty, it shows that there was an attempt made to open page "/page.php" on the server (the link in access log has no domain).

```
    xx.xx.xx.xx - - [19/May/2014:12:02:49 +0100] "GET /page.php 
    HTTP/1.0" 404 285 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; 
    Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0"
```

Server error log (/var/log/httpd/error_log) gives this error:

```
    [Mon May 19 12:02:49 2014] [error] [client xx.xx.xx.xx] 
    File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs
```

So it would seem that something is stripping the domain name from "http://b.com/page.php" and the resulting URL that wget is trying to connect to is "/page.php". This will not work, given that the server has many domains on it.

Has anyone come across this? Is there some setting in wget or php or apache that would cause this to not happen? I tried different things based on suggestions regarding similar problems, but nothing has worked so far.

Thanks.

Comment: That means [document root]/page.php not exist. Depends on the virtual host settigs.

Comment: http://b.com/page.php does exist. I can open it from a browser. The access log file for b.com should record the /page.php request, even if the file doesn't exist. But there is nothing in b.com apache log file.

Comment: The wget must send any header (eg the host header) to access the virtual host of that domain. Try to download any available script with `var_dump($_SERVER);`

Comment: I added --header="Host: b.com" to the wget call (b.com is the host obtained from $_SERVER), and still there is no change.

Comment: Can you access `http://b.com/page.php` from the browser? Headers not needed if already there. This path is unclear `/var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs/pages`. Whether it file or directory? Check the config for any rewriting rules, try to rename the script.

Comment: Yes, I can open it from the browser. I can also run the same PHP script (the one with wget command) from command line and wget works - but when opened from browser, it gives the error above. (The path in error log was incorrect, and I corrected it: /var/www/vhosts/default/htdocs is a directory.) I'm investigating the config, but nothing so far.

Comment: Check also for PHP restrictions like [safe mode](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode.php). Try [`shell_exec()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead of exec.

Comment: Maybe it's a behavior of the wget itself, that needs on proper shell environment or user rights.

Answer (score 0):

The problem turned out to be not in wget, but in firewall settings. The wget call, executed from behind the firewall, was resolving the domain to an external IP address, and connections to the external IP address were failing. Correcting this in the firewall fixed the wget problem.